# Filter a JSON Model based on key of an object UI5

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

I have a JSON Model say:-

```
var currency = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
var currenices = [{"name":"Indian National Rupee", "code":"INR"},
                  {"name":"Euro", "code":"EUR"},
                  {"name":"U.S.Dollars", "code":"USD"},
                  {"name":"Chilean Peso", "code":"CLP"},
                  {"name":"New Zealand Dollar", "code":"NZD"}]
currency.setData(currenices);
```

How can I apply "new sap.ui.model.Filter(sPath, FilterOperator, value1, value2,...,...)" to this model. I want to get the currency name given the code.
I know this can be done during data binding, but I want to do this directly to the model.

I applied the 'filter' function to the array and was able to filter the name given the code.
Is It possible to do the same using model.Filter?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Not sure what you're after... do you want to find the 'name' for a certain 'code' (i.e., something like the sql SELECT name WHERE code = 'EUR') or do you need a filter (i.e., reducing your list to a single entry)?

Comment: I want to get the name given the code (same as the sql you mentioned). I have a value help input box for curency which needs to be prepopulated as soon as user navigates to this page. I only get the currency code from the service and hence I have created a UI model to map the currency code to currnecy name and display the currency name on the input box always. So if I get 'USD' from the service, I display  U.S.Dollars in the input box.currently I am using 'foreach' to loop through the array(currencies) and map the code to get the name. please let me know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. The Filter is bound to List Binding. Please see my answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387580/not-possible-to-set-filter-value-using-data-binding) about Filter function in UI5 data binding. Why do you want to do this directly 
to the model?

Regards,
Allen

Updated Answer:

Formatter function for data binding seems to be one solution for your case. Since you can maintain your own Currency Map, you can define the formatter and do the following:

```
var currencyMap = {"EUR":"Euro","USD":"U.S.Dollars"} // 

currencyFormatter: function(sCurrency) {

    return currencyMap[sCurrency];  
}
```

Details about UI5 formatter function, please see the [documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/0c803921b1bf4b3a97a038fbd51ef542.html).