# How create sorters and Filters of Row Repeater in XML view of SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to create Sorters and Filters of Row Repeater Element in Xml View of SAPUI5.

I tried to create by using the JavaScript View but no Luck.

How can I write Sorters and Filters of Row Repeater in XML View?

```
<c:RowRepeater rows="{path: bindingpath}" id="rowRepeater" title="Companies Filter">

           <c:filters>
             <c:RowRepeaterFilter id="filter1" text="Filter Text Goes Here" filter="{path: bindingpath, operator: "EQ", value: 'my value'}">

                </c:RowRepeaterFilter>

           <c:filters>
            <c:sorters>
                <c:RowRepeaterSorter id="sorter2" text="Sorter 1" sorter="{path: bindingpath, descending: true}">

                </c:RowRepeaterSorter>
                <c:RowRepeaterSorter id="sorter1" text="Sorter 2"  sorter="{path: bindingpath, descending: true}">

                </c:RowRepeaterSorter>

            </c:sorters>
            <core:Title text="Companies Filter"></core:Title>
            <c:rows>
                <Panel>
                    <content>

                        <!-- Display Binding Elements -->

                    </content>
                </Panel>
            </c:rows>
        </c:RowRepeater>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind filter values in XML view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41777791/how-to-bind-filter-values-in-xml-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot "completely" write the sorter in XML (which is a shame, I fully agree!)

I believe the reason for that is the signature of the `c:RowRepeaterSorter`'s `sorter` propery; it expects an object of type `sap.ui.model.Sorter` and it doesn't get properly recognized from specifying an object like `{path : 'field', descending : true}`

A solution would be the following:

1. Write your `RowRepeaterSorter` as you normally would do, without the `sorter` property:

   ```
   <c:sorters>
       <c:RowRepeaterSorter id="sorter2" text="Sorter 1" />
       <c:RowRepeaterSorter id="sorter1" text="Sorter 2" />
   </c:sorters>
   ```
2. In your controller's `onAfterRendering` event handler, set the actual sorters:

   ```
   var oSorter1 = this.getView().byId("sorter1");
   oSorter1.setSorter(new sap.ui.model.Sorter({path : "field1", descending : "true"}));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

At last I found the answer for this question.

Filters are not supporting dynamic Binding. The Filter can be achieved by the javascript controller.

I found this from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387580/not-possible-to-set-filter-value-using-data-binding/25394715#25394715).

Coming to Row Repeater Sorters I tried sorter by following syntax:

```
<c:RowRepeater rows="{path: bindingpath}" id="rowRepeater" title="Companies Filter">


                <c:sorters>
                    <c:RowRepeaterSorter id="sorter2" text="Sorter 1" sorter="{path: bindingpath, descending: true}">

                    </c:RowRepeaterSorter>
                    <c:RowRepeaterSorter id="sorter1" text="Sorter 2"  sorter="{path: bindingpath, descending: true}">

                    </c:RowRepeaterSorter>

                </c:sorters>
                <core:Title text="Companies Filter"></core:Title>
                <c:rows>
                    <Panel>
                        <content>

                            <!-- Display Binding Elements -->

                        </content>
                    </Panel>
                </c:rows>
            </c:RowRepeater>
```

I am not getting any sorters functionality. But buttons are coming on the screen. For now I am assuming that sorter is not supported directly.