# How to bind filter values in XML view

Tags: sapui5

I am developing an app using worklist template of Web IDE. I got stuck in with an issue in binding filter values to items attribute of `sap.m.Table` along with OData - EntitySet path. As you can see in below screen shot, `value1` needs to get value of property `"name"`. I guess the syntax that I am using might be wrong.

Please suggest on how to pass dynamic values to filter.

[image: Object.view.xml]

With the above code in XML view I am seeing below show values in back end.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not possible to set Filter value using data binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387580/not-possible-to-set-filter-value-using-data-binding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, UI5 doesn't support binding syntax for `filters` and `sorter` yet. The strings in `value1` (and `value2`) will not be parsed but taken literally. And it looks like such bindings [won't be supported in near future](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1040#event-701844308) either despite being [on the backlock](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/130#issuecomment-118313527) and one of the highly requested features.

Until then, we've to use [bindItems](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#bindItems), set `sap.ui.model.Filter` instances on the `filters` property of the binding info object, and get the filter values from the desired model manually instead of using binding syntax.

Example: https://embed.plnkr.co/AoIZI4/